# About React Memo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am learning React.

There are several componentized buttons.
When I click on one button, the other button components, including the parent component, are also re-rendered.

```js
import { useState } from 'react'

const Button = ({ setState, text }) => {

  console.log(`${text} rendering`)

  return (<button
    onClick={e => setState(prevState => !prevState)}
  >
    {text}
  </button>)
}

const Page = () => {

  console.log('Page rendering')

  const [aaa, setAaa] = useState(false)
  const [bbb, setBbb] = useState(false)

  return (<>

    <div>
      <Button
        setState={setAaa}
        text="A button"
      />
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(aaa, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>

    <div>
      <Button
        setState={setBbb}
        text="B button"
      />
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(bbb, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>

  </>)
}

export default Page
```

If anyone has more information, we would appreciate it if you could enlighten us.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's generally recomended to **mark an answer** as accpeted when it solves you problem, it will help future reader with similar problem. You can do this by checking ✔ in the top left corner of the answer.

Comment: I have checked now.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anytime you set state in a component, the component and all of its children will re-render. You could memoize the children by wrapping them in [`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) so that if their props don't change they don't re-render. However, that will increase the memory footprint of your app, so often it only makes sense to memoize components that are expensive/slow to re-render, and your `Button` component is fairly simple to render.

Comment: I see, so there are cases where it is better not to memoize. It is a good lesson to learn. Thank you very much.